# How to put snackbar button response in one suspend function in Kotlin jetpack

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-snackbar, suspend

How to put snackbar button response in one suspend function in Kotlin jetpack.
I have one SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed for all my snackbars.
And I have suspend fun for my snackbar:

```
suspend fun snackBar(
    snackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState, context: Context,
    buttonText: Int = settings,
    snackbarText: Int = permission_access
) =
    snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
        context.resources.getString(snackbarText),
        context.resources.getString(buttonText),
        duration = SnackbarDuration.Short
    )
```

Now I need to call this function like:

```
val contextSnackBar = LocalContext.current as ComponentActivity
snackBarScope.launch {
when (snackBar(context = context, snackbarHostState = snackbarHostState)) {
     SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed -> {
          contextSnackBar.appSettings().apply {
          contextSnackBar.startActivity(this)
          }
      }
}
```

But how can I put SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed in my suspend function?

Comment: You already return SnackbarResult from snackbarHostState.showSnackbar in your suspend function. It can be SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed or SnackbarResult.Dismissed and it is decided by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, check out the [`showSnackbar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/SnackbarHostState#showSnackbar(kotlin.String,kotlin.String,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarDuration)) documentation:

```
suspend fun showSnackbar(
    message: String,
    actionLabel: String? = null,
    withDismissAction: Boolean = false,
    duration: SnackbarDuration = if (actionLabel == null) SnackbarDuration.Short else SnackbarDuration.Indefinite
): SnackbarResult
```

It returns a SnackbarResult which is

> SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed if option action has been clicked or SnackbarResult.Dismissed if snackbar has been dismissed via timeout or by the user

So this will set the SnackbarResult automatically, you do not have to set it manually. Whenever the user clicks on the action that you defined via `actionLabel`, the function will automatically return `SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed`.